# Sending user comments on Email in android studio

Tags: android, email

I am trying to make a "Contact us" page where I am taking user comments/ Suggestions along with their name and email and want to send them to my gmail account. I don't want intents. I have read the documentation on Java API but they are sending a hard coded message "Hello World" 
I don't want that. And I have no idea how to achieve the task I am trying to do. Any guidance and help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I have tried the tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/ which sends the automated email on button click. I dont want the hard coded message. I have made the layout and want to send the message entered by the user along with the email, name and phone number to my gmail account. I am new to android so I don't know how this will be achieved. I will appreciate any kind of suggestions and help
[Contact us layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL6kP.png)

Comment: I don't want intents.? Why wouldn't you want intents? This is super easy using intent.

Comment: actually I am making an app for Blind people and want to send the email right away with a voice command "Send" I know how to do it i just want to send the mail without further interaction

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far? Any code? Any issues?

Comment: I havent tried anything which I want, I have tried the tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/ but it only sends the hard coded message. Let me update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this link http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/ again.

They are not sending only hard coded message but as an example they have taken TextView with 'Hello World' , you can use any controls that you want like EditText and when user will enter those details then get the values from EditText and do the concatenation of those values and make one string,store in a variable and use that string to send in a email as body.

You just have to change the value in below line in SendMail AsyncTask class' doInBackground method

```
m.setBody($body_variable);
```

I hope this will help you , Feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you ! this seems to solve my issue. I will try and notify you in a while.

Comment: Are you going to test it now ?